# pandas read_csv skiprows - determine rows to skip

Tags: python, pandas

below is a csv snippet with some dummy headers while the actual frame anchored by `beerId`:

```
This work is an unpublished, copyrighted work and contains confidential information.  
beer consumption    
consumptiondate 7/24/2018
consumptionlab  H1
numbeerssuccessful  40
numbeersfailed  0
totalnumbeers   40
consumptioncomplete TRUE

beerId  Book
341027  Northern Light
```

this `df = pd.read_csv(path_csv, header=8)` code works, but the issue is that header is not always in 8 depending on a day.  cannot figure out how to use `lambda` from [help](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) as in

> **skiprows** : list-like or integer or callable, default None
>
> Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at
>   the start of the file.
>
> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the row
>   indices, returning True if the row should be skipped and False
>   otherwise. An example of a valid callable argument would be lambda x:
>   x in [0, 2].

to find the index row of `beerId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need preprocessing first:

```
path_csv = 'file.csv'
with open(path_csv) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    #get list of all possible lins starting by beerId
    num = [i for i, l in enumerate(lines) if l.startswith("beerId" )]
    #if not found value return 0 else get first value of list subtracted by 1
    num = 0 if len(num) == 0 else num[0] - 1
    print (num)
    8


df = pd.read_csv(path_csv, header=num)
print (df)
             beerId  Book
0  341027  Northern Light
```